Differences between "bring" and "take"
I was thinking about these words and made some sample sentences
"I'm going to bring my friends to the party" = "I am going to take my friends to the party"
"I am going to bring some food to the party" = "I am going to take some food to the party"
"Bring the items to the table" = "Take the items to the table"
All of these sound fine and natural to me. Are they always interchangeable?

Did you search this question on this site?

Clearly Bring the items to the table would be said by someone who was near to the table, Take... by someone who was some distance from it. As to the other two, you would probably use bring when speaking to the host of the planned party, take when speaking to other people.

There are a few similar questions here if you search but this has the best answer. However "bring (something) to the table" is an idiom so if you're using it as an idiom, then you can't change the verb.

@KateBunting, to be honest both sound perfectly natural to me, but maybe I have been using it incorrectly the whole time

I said nothing about either being unnatural! Both are fine in different circumstances.

bring tends to be towards a stationary speaker and take tends to be away from a stationary speaker, and by "stationary" I mean that they are at a location, not that they are absolutely motionless.  Speakers who are moving from one location to another tend to be able to use either verb.

Welcome, John. Glad you could come. I see you've taken brought some friends with you. Please come in, all of you.

Back at John's house the land-line phone rings, and his sister answers:

Hello, this is Mary Smith.
-- Hi, Mary. This is John's guitar teacher, Bill White. Is John there?
No. He's gone to a party and has brought taken a few friends along with him. He said to tell you that he can call you back tomorrow.

Since John will be on-the-move, he can say either:

Mary, I'm going to a party tonight and I'm going to [take | bring] some friends with me. Bill White, my guitar teacher, might phone about a guitar he is selling. If he does call, please let him know that I can call him back tomorrow.

This rule is not carved in stone, but is merely a "rule-of-thumb".
Something is brought me-ward, to me or towards me.
Someting is taken away from me, away from where I am (was, or will be).
I am bringing | taking something with me.
NOTE: The pronouns me and I (and us) are meant to refer to the speaker(s) here.

In your second example where you say "Is John there?" I don't know why, but I usually say "brought a few friends along with him". I guess I have been using it incorrectly this whole time, thanks!

I would not go as far as to call it "incorrect" by any means, as these are subjective verbs. If Mary is thinking of John arriving at the party accompanied by friends, she could easily use brought, whereas if she's thinking him as departing their home accompanied by friends, she might well say taken.  But the host of the party wouldn't say "I see you've taken some friends".

The two words imply different directions - you bring something to someone, whereas you take something away from them. That doesn't mean you can't say "take to..." but it still implies you intend to take it from one place and transport it somewhere else.
It all depends on the perspective of the speaker and audience. If you were speaking with a fellow guest of the party you would say "I'm going to take a bottle", but if you were talking to the host you'd say "I'm going to bring a bottle".

Yes,  indeed. Who is being spoken to is also a determining factor in this spatial reckoning.   But I think when speaking to a fellow guest one could say take or bring a bottle.  In the US in many states that control alcohol, we have restaurants that do not serve wine or alcohol but the guest is allowed to bring their own bottle.  So we would say to a couple we're having dinner with at a BYOB (bring your own bottle) restaurant, "We''ll bring a red if you're bringing a white."

And I think even if we were having dinner at the home of a mutual friend, we would say "I'm bringing a bottle." to a fellow guest. But certainly "bringing" if speaking to the host, as you say.
